# get javascript variable into webbrowser control winforms

Tags: javascript, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I'm using a webbrowser control in visual studio 2010 to invoke JS script.I'm able to call a function from the web browser but i'm looking to get a varible value from JS and use it in the winform.

I have this JS code for exemple :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f() {
var val=0;
return val;
}
</script>
```

The C# code is not working :

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("f");
```

what's the right way to invoke the JS function and get the variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InvokeScript will return the value which the javascript function returns. You just need to be a bit careful about it's type. Numbers and strings will be returned a c# strings.